# Size of QByteArray is hard to compute?

Tags: qt, qbytearray

Recently I programmed to do file transmission with Qt. Thought it worked now, I'm still curious about what happened. Please help me find out the reason. Many thanks.

**Why the size of head is bigger than the sum of sizeof(qin32), sizeof(qint32) and length of file name?(I guess it is the reason of function - setVersion())**

```
QFileInfo info(file_to_send.fileName());
QByteArray head;
QDataStream out(&head, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_0);
out << qint32(file_to_send.size() + info.fileName().length() + sizeof(qint32)*2)
    << qint32(info.fileName().length())
    << info.fileName();
tcpClient.write(head);
```

Comment: Client Head Size:  40 |
Client Header: [  252592  ] [  14  ] [  "Screenshot.png"  ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made it to complicated. Pattern is like that:

```
QFileInfo info(file_to_send.fileName());
QByteArray head;
QDataStream out(&head, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_0);
out << qint32(0)
    << info.fileName(); // << YouCanAddMoreStuffHere;

out.device()->seek(0);
out << qint32(out.length());

tcpClient.write(head);
```

and read code:

```
void SomeClass::slotReadClient() { // slot connected to readyRead signal of QTcpSocket
    QTcpSocket *tcpSocket = (QTcpSocket*)sender();
    QDataStream clientReadStream(tcpSocket);

    while(true) {
        if (!next_block_size) {
            if (tcpSocket->bytesAvailable() < sizeof(qint32)) { // are size data available
                break;
            }
            clientReadStream >> next_block_size;
        }

        if (tcpSocket->bytesAvailable() < next_block_size) {
            break;
        }
        QString fileName;
        clientReadStream >> fileName; // >> YouCanAddMoreStuffHere; // same as above

        next_block_size = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you left out the full size, which was used to update my progressbar in server. Would you mind helping me solve my confusion?

Comment: QData stream is storing size of the string so you don't have to write it too. In this pattern the begging size is needed only to verify that full content is already available since `QDataStream` and `QTcpSocket` doesn't work well if not all stream data are available (sockets passes data in chunks which doesn't have to reflect sending process). Anyway `QDataStream` stores size of item if it is necessary.

Comment: Oh, I just realized your meaning. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`info.filename()` [writes out its own length](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/datastreamformat.html)

if you don't want that then you can do

```
QFileInfo info(file_to_send.fileName());
QByteArray head;
QDataStream out(&head, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_0);
QByteArray filename = info.fileName().toLatin1();
out << qint32(file_to_send.size() + filename .length() + sizeof(qint32)*2);
    << qint32(filename .length())
out.writeRawData(fileName.constData(), filename.length());
tcpClient.write(head);
```

using `writeRawData` which bypasses any built in encoding

Comment: Great, very helpful! Do I have to use the same class in client and server? I used QString in client and I found that using QByteArray (in >> QByteArray) in server didn't work.

Comment: Yes, you're right! 4 + 4 + 4(QString length) + 2*(QString, UTF-16) = 4 + 4 + 4 + 2*strlen("Screenshot.png") = 40(header size)